# django-celery vs django-celery-beat with Django 2.2

Tags: django, celery

We have been working with `celery` and `django-celery` till now but recently we planned to migrate our codebase to `Django==2.2` and looks like django-celery doesn't have support for Django==2.2 yet.

With `django-celery` we could configure periodic tasks from django admin. Is it safe to assume that if I want the similar functionality then apart from `Celery` package and running celerybeat instance I would have to install `django-celery-beat` package instead of `django-celery` - without doing massive code changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-celery` can be removed. I used it but celery can work fine without it.
Just see https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Your tasks remains the same.

I used periodic tasks with the following packages installed:

```
celery==4.4.7
kombu==4.6.10
django-celery-beat==1.4.0
```

The `INSTALLED_APP` : add `'django_celery_beat',`

example:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

@shared_task(longname=_("Send mail to administrators"))
def mail_admins_delayed(subject, message):
    mail_admins(subject, message)
```

Start celery from your django workdir with

```
celery worker --app <djangoprojectname>
celery -A <djangoprojectname> beat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kutera! Looks like my assumption was right.